Android custom drawable attributes
I've developed a custom drawable for rendering a stylied field. It has two custom colour fields defined in values/attrs.xml:
<attr format="color" name="fieldColor" />
<attr format="color" name="chalkColor" />

These colours are referenced in values/themes.xml:
<style name="Base.Theme.Game" parent="Theme.Material3.DayNight.NoActionBar">
  <item name="fieldColor">@color/lightGreen</item>
  <item name="trackColor">@color/black</item>

and values-night/themes.xml:
<style name="Base.Theme.Game" parent="Theme.Material3.DayNight.NoActionBar">
  <item name="fieldColor">@color/darkGreen</item>
  <item name="trackColor">@color/white</item>

from colours defined in values\colors.xml
In my XML drawable file drawable/ic_field.xml I use the attrubutes thus:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<drawable xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    class="org.dobbo.game.drawable.FieldDrawable"
    app:fieldColor="?attr/fieldColor"
    app:trackColor="?attr/trackColor"
    app:trackWidth="@dimen/field_strokeWidth" />

Which correctly shows the colours in the lefthand margin.  But at runtime I get the following exception when trying to extract the first attrubute:
Caused by: java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Failed to resolve attribute
  at index 0: TypedValue{t=0x2/d=0x7f0301da a=-1}, theme=null
  at android.content.res.TypedArray.getColor(TypedArray.java:529)
  at org.dobbo.game.FieldDrawable.inflate(FieldDrawable.java:149)
  at android.graphics.drawable.DrawableInflater.inflateFromXmlForDensity(DrawableInflater.java:141)
  at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromXmlInnerForDensity(Drawable.java:1394)
  at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromXmlForDensity(Drawable.java:1355)
  at android.content.res.ResourcesImpl.loadXmlDrawable(ResourcesImpl.java:945)
  at android.content.res.ResourcesImpl.loadDrawableForCookie(ResourcesImpl.java:888)
  ... 94 more

Where the code looks like this:
@Override
public void inflate(final @NonNull Resources resources,
                    final @NonNull XmlPullParser parser,
                    final @NonNull AttributeSet attrs,
                    final @Nullable Resources.Theme theme)
 throws IOException, XmlPullParserException {
        super.inflate(resources, parser, attrs, theme);

  final TypedArray styling = null != theme
                                   ? theme.obtainStyledAttributes(attrs, R.styleable.FieldDrawable, 0, 0)
                                   : resources.obtainAttributes(attrs, R.styleable.FieldDrawable);
  try {
    setFieldColor(styling.getColor(R.styleable.FieldDrawable_fieldColor, getFieldColor()));

Many thanks for your help.
